# Apply 'if' condition to compare two pandas column and form a third column with the value of the second column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I have two columns in pandas dataframe and want to compare their values against each other and return a third column processing a simple formula.

```
if post_df['pos'] == 1:

    if post_df['lastPrice'] < post_df['exp']:
        post_df['profP'] = post_df['lastPrice'] - post_df['ltP']
        post_df['pos'] = 0
    else:
        post_df['profP'] = post_df['lastPrice'] - post_df['ltP']
```

However, when I run the above code I get the following error:

```
    if post_df['pos'] == 1:
File "/Users/srikanthiyer/Environments/emacs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1479, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have tried using np.where which works but since I intend to build a complex conditional structure want to keep it simple using if statements.

Comment: You get the error because `post_df['pos']`is a Series object containing many values. Can you provide examples of your input data and expected result so that it's clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: you got this error because post_df['pos']  represente all the diferent values of the column 'pos'. so to be able to compare them you must specify wich value you want to compare to 1 .

exemple : if you put post_df['po'].all() == 1 this condition will be True only if all values on the column are equale to 1

Comment: if you can create a dataframe sample similar to your original one(may be  not more than 5 rows) and an expected output dataframe, may be you can get better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
def calculate_profp(row):
    profP = None
    if row['pos'] == 1:
        if row['lastPrice'] < row['exp']:
            profP = row['lastPrice'] - row['ltP']
        else:
            profP = row['lastPrice'] - row['ltP']
    return profP

post_df['profP'] = post_df.apply(calculate_profp, axis=1)
```

What do you want to do with rows where `row['pos']` is not `1`?

afterwards, you can run:

```
post_df['pos'] = post_df.apply(
    lambda row: 0 if row['pos'] == 1 and row['lastPrice'] < row['exp'] else row['pos'],
    axis=1)
```

to set `pos` from `1` to `0`

or:

```
post_df['pos'] = post_df['pos'].map(lambda pos: 0 if pos == 1 else pos)
```

Comment: Hi Granny, thanks for your reply which works. However, I also want to update the row['pos'] with 0 when the if condition (checking the prices) is satisfied. To answer your question there will be no processing when the row['pos'] is 0.

Comment: I added code to update pos. Do I get my first ever upvote?